# Symfony redirect in helper service does not work

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, symfony4

### Introduction

For my personal project i am using

- `Symfony v4.2` with
- `XAMPP` and
- `Widows 10 Pro`

In order to not to display route parameters in URL i save them in the table.
Then in the controller i check if there is variable (that keeps UUID that corresponds to route parameters) in the session.

If i get no variable in session it should redirect to section start page, where UUID and initial data in the table are setup.

Redirect logic is extracted to helper service. In order to redirect to work there are copied functions `redirectToRoute` and `redirect`

I test this functionalit by deleting php session variables in temp folder and PHPSESSID cookie in the browser.

### Problem

The prolem is - it does not redirect to secton start page.

I can see that correct if branch is selected, but then it "just stops" and does not execute redirect.

### Code

```
public function checkWhereaboutsExist()
{
   $em = $this->entityManager;
   $repo_whereabouts = $em->getRepository(Whereabouts::class);

   $whereabouts = $this->session->get('whereabouts');
   if (($whereabouts === null) || ($whereabouts === ''))
   {
       $data = 'whereabouts === '.$whereabouts;
       dump($data);
       /*
       HERE IT STOPS
       */
       return $this->redirectToRoute('section_start');
   }
   else
   {
       $my_whereabouts = $repo_whereabouts->getWhereabouts($whereabouts);
       if (!$my_whereabouts)
       {
           return $this->redirectToRoute('section_start');
       }
   }
}
```

### Question

Does enyone have some ideas about what is the culprit in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to inject the router into your service class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
```

class MyService
{
    private $router;

```
public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function checkWhereaboutsExist()
{
    // your code ...

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('section_start'));
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is correct. I was close to solution yet `new RedirectResponse` was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hummmm, i suppose that your code is in a service and not in your controller ?
You can't redirect from a service but only from controller as controller send the final response.

You have to return a boolean from your service and redirect from your controller :

```
public function hasToGoToStart()
{
   $em = $this->entityManager;
   $repo_whereabouts = $em->getRepository(Whereabouts::class);

   $whereabouts = $this->session->get('whereabouts');
   if (($whereabouts === null) || ($whereabouts === ''))
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       $my_whereabouts = $repo_whereabouts->getWhereabouts($whereabouts);
       if (!$my_whereabouts)
       {
           return true;
       }
   }

   return false;
}
```

and in your controller :

```
if ($myService->hasToGoToStart()) {
    // redirect
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you are correct that a listener is being used then you should perhaps be aware that a kernel request listener can return a response via the GetResponseEvent data structure.  No controller required.  So right idea but the implementation needs a bit of work.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! Yet i prefer Roberts solution as it picks up where stoped and fixes my mistake.

Comment: I confirm that Cerad comment is the best way to handle this ;-)